# Show ProgressDialog while in handler background event

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar, android-handler

I want to show message with the text Scanning for 10 seconds.

Normally we do the following when we use `onPreExecute` in `AsyncTask`,

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = 
new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()); 
dialogo1.setMessage("Scanning...");            
dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
```

But how to do the same when using **handler** like the following---

```
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
if (enable) {
    // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mScanning = false;
        Log.d(TAG,getCtx() + "run stopLeScan");
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }, SCAN_PERIOD);
    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" scanLeDevice startLeScan:"+enable);
    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+ " scanLeDevice stopLeScan:"+enable);
    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

So while the scanning is in background process for 10 seconds, lets provide a dialog till it completes.

Comment: what do you want to achievew?

Comment: I want alert dialog for the time handler is performing scan for LE device i.e. for the time 10000 milliseconds as given by SCAN_PERIOD. How can we do with the above method in handler ?

Answer (score 0):

i think....maybe

```
if (enable) {
     //show dialog box here
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    mScanning = false;
    //dismiss dialog box here
    Log.d(TAG,getCtx() + "run stopLeScan");
    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}, SCAN_PERIOD);
Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" scanLeDevice startLeScan:"+enable);
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
} else {
Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+ " scanLeDevice stopLeScan:"+enable);
mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in handler like this--

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Context);
    pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait!");
    pDialog.setMessage("Scanning...");
    pDialog.show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, SCAN_PERIOD);
```